# chalav stam during aseres yemei tshuvah

Tags: stringency-chumrah, aseres-yemei-teshuva, chalav-yisrael-jewishmilk, pat-yisrael

The Shulchan Aruch says the during aseres yemei tshuva one who eats pas akum(palter) during the year should refrain during these days.

Does this extend to those who are lenient with chalav Stam?

Comment: I had the same thought. In the times of the S"'A, nobody drank non-Jewish milk, so it would not have come up as a thought to be strict this time of year. But it follow that it would have been included.

Comment: The Sefarim say that any Chumra one could take on themseles they should.

Comment: @fred that looks like a good answer,thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[R' Dovid Feinstein](http://matzav.com/rav-dovid-feinstein-a-treife-knife-and-halacha-lemaaseh-on-cholov-yisroel) rules that *chalav stam* in the US is permissible *me'ikar hadin* year-round, so it is not comparable to *pas palter* and one need not be strict to the same degree of *pas palter*. However, he does maintain that *chalav Yisrael* is ideal, so it seems like he might consider it a reasonable optional practice to undertake during the *aseres y'mei t'shuva*.

By contrast, [R' Doniel Neustadt](http://books.google.com/books?id=t_g7H2olIBUC&pg=PA4&lpg=PA4#v=onepage&q&f=false) cites the *Sha'ar HaTziyun* (609:1) and the *Igros Moshe* (OC 3, 12) as saying that "during the Aseres yemei teshuva we should be stringent when it comes to all questionable issues." R' Neustadt writes that consuming non-*chalav Yisrael* dairy in the US is a controversial leniency, and he rules that, even if one is lenient year-round, "it is not appropriate to rely on this leniency during the *Aseres yemei teshuvah*."